# How to add like button in class based List view in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have added like button in detail view but could't able make the logic to add like button in List View. I have commented out the logic which I have used in Detail View below which is failed to create like button in List View. Can anyone suggest me to do the best way, can somebody help me with this please.

### model.py

Codes in models.py

```
class AlbumVoteManager(models.Manager):

    def get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(self,album,user):
        try:
            return Vote.objects.get(album=album,user=user)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Vote(album=album,user=user)

class AlbumVote(models.Model):
    UP = 1
    DOWN = -1
    VALUE_CHOICE = ((UP, "️"),(DOWN, "️"),)


    like = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=VALUE_CHOICE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = AlbumVoteManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'album')
```

### form.py

Codes in form.py

```
class AlbumVoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AlbumVote
        fields = ['like']
```

### views.py

Codes in views.py

```
class AlbumListView(ListView):
    model = Album
    paginate_by = 5

    # def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    #     ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    #     if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
    #         vote = 
AlbumVote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(album=self.object_list.object, user = self.request.user)
    #         if vote.id:
    #             vote_url = reverse('music:album_vote_update', kwargs={'album_id':vote.album.id,'pk':vote.id})
    #         else:
    #             vote_url = reverse('music:album_vote_create', kwargs={'album_id':self.object_list.object.id})


    #         vote_form = AlbumVoteForm(instance=vote)
    #         ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
    #         ctx['vote_url'] = vote_url
    #     return ctx
```

### album_list.html

Codes in album list view.

```
  <div class="container">
    {% if object_list %}
        {% for album in object_list %}

        <div class="card my-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              Featured
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">

                    <a href="{% url 'music:detail_view' pk=album.id %}"><strong>{{album.title}}</strong></a>

              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{album.discription}}.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be implemented by passing a unique id to the buttons while the classes are the same for all on the template.
You can make reference on this article on Medium [here](https://michealscode.medium.com/django-ajax-like-and-upvote-button-on-listview-solved-in-5-simple-steps-96dbdc39daca) which implemented something similar using AJAX